# What's the role of underscore in print function in Python?

Tags: python, pycharm

Accidentally I printed something like:

```
print(var, __)
```

I cannot understand what's being produced. It seems to grab history items depending on how long the _____ is. I'm using Pycharm.

Comment: These variable names that consist of one or more underscores are temporary or "magic" variables created by environments such as ipython and even python's own REPL. Sometimes they are convenient for interactive use. Try to create a simple script and refer to `_` or `__` -  you'll see they are not defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__` is a variable name.

`_` and `___` are different variable names.

`print(var, __)` prints the content of `var` followed by the content of `__`.

Depending on the context, `_` / `__` / `___` may be pre-filled.
In a Jupyter Notebook, these are the 3 previous cell results.

Answer (score 3):

What you see is likely the [output caching of IPython](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/reference.html#output-caching-system):

> For output that is returned from actions, a system similar to the
>   input cache exists but using _ instead of _i. Only actions that
>   produce a result (NOT assignments, for example) are cached. If you are
>   familiar with Mathematica, IPython’s _ variables behave exactly like
>   Mathematica’s % variables.
>
> The following variables always exist:
>
> ```
>     [_] (a single underscore): stores previous output, like Python’s default interpreter.
>     [__] (two underscores): next previous.
>     [___] (three underscores): next-next previous.
> ```